# Non-responsive site will not resize to fit mobile browsers

Tags: css

I'm trying to take a template that was designed to be responsive and make it "unresponsive."

http://myhurlburt.com/NEW/bowling.php

The width of the page is set to 960px. When I view it on an iPad or iPhone, you have to scroll to the side to see the entire page. Do you know what in my CSS is causing that? I would like the entire site to "fit" into a browser so the user does not have to scroll to the side.

Comment: This is too general. Converting a site to be responsive is a relatively big project. Look up media queries, and read some responsive website articles.

Comment: Josh - I am not trying to make the site responsive, as in move the menus and images around to fit on a phone. I simply want a small version of the site to fit within a browser window, like this current site does: myhurlburt.com.

Comment: You need to include at least some code here. Don't just drop a link to your site and expect people to view source and then follow all the CSS and open that up. It has to be useful to more than just your website

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a big job to change an unresponsive site to a responsive one.

But you could try something like this to get started.. .wraper currently has it's width set to 960px.

`.wraper{
 width:100%;
 max-width:960px;
}`

Answer (score 1):

use % for width, height and other margins. Use media queries also. If not, do zoom:1(2,3 or something);

Answer (score 0):

Start by scaling the website with `min/max widths` and additionally use `percentages` instead of `px`.